# How to retain all EXIF metadata in images on a Wagtail website?

Tags: django, image-processing, metadata, wagtail, exif

Wagtail seems to clear all (EXIF) metadata in generated thumbnails and custom sized copies of an image. Is this correct?

Is there a simple Wagtail way, in leaving all the image metadata? (SEO, Copyright...)

Thank you!

Comment: Thumbnails and such are usually generated by image libraries that don't necessarily have a routine to copy metadata.  Such data is rarely considered a priority for thumbnails.  You'll probably have to write the data yourself or modify the existing code to do so.